# Мне надо создать папку по пути, который укажет пользователь на Python3 (модуль os)

Tags: python

Мне надо создать папку по пути, который укажет пользователь на Python3. Я пролистал весь интернет, но так и не нашёл (модуль os).

Comment: Все можно. Проблема в чем конкретно, как запросить путь у пользователя или как создать папку?

Comment: запросить путь у пользователя

Comment: Через input пробовали? Вы полностью напишите, что конкретно вы хотите получить, чтобы мне по одному слову не нужно было из вас вытягивать.

Comment: смотрите, я знаю как создать папку по определённому пути (те написать в коде), а вот чтобы пользователь ввёл путь и по этому пути создалась папка.  input() не работал или я это сделал как-то не правильно.

Comment: input вполне работает. Добавьте код, как именно пробовали делать.

Comment: import os

Pyt = input()
os.mkdir("Pyt history")

я ещё много как пробовал, но не получалось

Comment: Там уже ответили, но спасибо

Comment: Ну вот нужно переменную передавать, без кавычек, тогда будет работать.

Comment: спасибо тебе тоже, но как сделать так, что бы оно само добавляла папку которую надо создать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ сделать через input:

```py
import os

path = input("Path: ") # Получаем путь. В этом пути должно быть имя новой папки

os.mkdir(path) # Создаём
```

[os.mkdir](https://proglib.io/p/samouchitel-po-python-dlya-nachinayushchih-chast-15-metody-raboty-s-faylami-i-faylovoy-sistemoy-2023-02-06#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%20Python,(%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82.)

Comment: спасибо! Не знаю почему я так тупил

Comment: Это конечно помогло, но можно как-то добавить чтобы оно само создавало нужные папки?

Comment: Нужные это какие?

Comment: папку history и common

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить по нужному тебе пути предопределённые папки, можно сложить их названия в список. Учти, что путь должен быть в формате C:\Твой_путь\

```
import os

lst=['history' ,'common']
path = input("Path: ")
for i in lst:
    os.mkdir(path + i)
```